# Which is the best tool available for load testing a Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 application?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

We are supposed to benchmark the performance of a dynamics ax 2012 application.
I have no prior experience in dynamics ax 2012 or load testing of desktop applications.
If anyone has worked on the same, please tell me the best available options.
From what I have been reading, I've gathered there is nothing like Application Benchmark Toolkit(which was for ax 2009) for ax 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Microsoft has released some benchmarking white papers, specifically the 'Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Day in the Life Benchmark' which gives some guidance on the sizing of environments. If you want to do your own load testing there is no easy way to get there currently. The closest you could reasonably get would be:

1. Writing a number of routines or jobs either in X++ or C# that call AX services and perform operations. This would let you do things like enter a large number of customers and orders and time the operations. This does not benchmark the client performance though.
2. Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate has UI automation testing tools that allow you to attach to an application and create UI tests that perform certain actions. You could use this to do manual tests in the Dynamics AX Client and then run them multiple times. Obviously this is only ideal if you need to test client performance.
3. According to recent posts from Convergence 2013, Microsoft is supposed to be releasing a load testing tool that seemingly meets your requirements in April/May 2013, so you may in fact luck out from a timing perspective unless you have a very tight implementation deadline.

A few quick rules of thumb from a performance perspective:

- Don't virtualize SQL Server, Microsoft says best case scenario (You have a really good SQL Admin), you'll take a 15% performance hit, and worse case it's closer to 60%.
- Use dedicated AOS's to handle things like batch jobs since they tend to get more and more involved as the system gets more mature.

Answer (score 0):

I'll reply to an old question, maybe it'll help some people in the future who land here through google.

In the meantime there is an application benchmark SDK for dynamics AX 2012.
You can find full documentation [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39082).

Basically it's a set of tests you run from visual studio, there are some standard tests available and the SDK allows you to perform your own tests